# Laravel Routes creating clashes with artisan migrate

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

**Scenario**

I have setup  Laravel application routes in such a way that, where

```
Route::group(["domain" => getSubDomain()->sub_domain,"middleware"=>
 ["guest"]], function () {
    //member routes
});
```

have one helper function getSubDomain()->sub_domain, which is checking sub_domain allowed in companies table. here is the helper function code

```
 $domain = \App\Model\Company::where('sub_domain', request()->getHost())->whereIn("company_type_id", (array)$company_type_id)->first();
    return !empty($domain) ? $domain : new \App\Model\Company(
        [
            "sub_domain"      => !in_array(4, $company_type_id) ? env("sub_domain") : "",
            "welcome_message" => env("welcome_message"),
            "domain_flag"     => "assets/images/dev-logo.png"
        ]);
```

In short this helper function will check in database about the sub domain is what? and based on valid sub domains routes are created.

**Issue**

This implementation is having requirement of `sub_domain` column from table and which is yet run using migration,

So when I am running migration using `php artisan migrate` it's showing me invalid column sub_domain.

This is creating conflict, that To run the migration routes are creating problem, and to prepare proper routes migration needs to be run.

> Earlier the same implementation was using .env variables but that was bit tedious as the support of new domains is required.

Can anybody have solution to run migration without interfering `Routes` ?

Comment: Just out of interest why aren't you using something like `'domain' => '{subdomain}.website.com' ` and then working with the subdomain in that way?

Comment: @Djave I have such requirements where user will be only able to access the specific routes based on sub domain they were assigned